# PostgreSQL - dump SELECT with schema

Tags: database, postgresql

I want to dump only part of the table (filtered using SELECT) with schema so I can take the dump and import it to other database without the need to create the schema first.

`COPY` command allows me to dump part of the table but without the schema.

`pg_dump` on the other hand allows me to dump the entire table with schema but I cannot filter the table beforehand.

How to solve this?

Comment: Do both, you could even merge both files to create a single file that can be used to import everything in another database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to do it like below:

Create a temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE tablefordump (
SELECT * FROM mytable ...)
```

Then take dump with "--table" option:

```
pg_dump --table=tablefordump
```